# Django looped form change values

Tags: python, forms, django-forms

I am new to Django and I am creating a loop form and it just works fine but I want to do a fine tuning that I can't find in any Django guides except if else method.What's your suggestion ?

- So I want {{field.label_tag}} to change to some other text because the
  values that I am retrieving are database values which is not good to use.
- I also want {{field}} value has a same default value already entered.
- The last thing that I want is to extend the form field lenght. Any ideas ?

  {%for field in form %}
      
      
      {{field.errors}}
      
        {{field.label_tag}} 
        {{field}} 
      
      {% endfor %}

Comment: I also have <div> and <span> within the codes that I pasted above but it's not showed there somehow